# Handling one template with multiple Django function

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a template which contains feature to "fetch" the details and "edit" using Bootstrap Modal, from a API.

I created 2 functions, one to display data and one to edit

views.py

```
def add_bom(request):
    ...
    context = {"sku_object": sku_object}    
    return render(request, 'BOM/add-bom.html', context=context)

def edit_bom_activity(request, bomNo, activity):
    ...
    context = {"filter_activity": filter_activity}
    return render(request, 'BOM/add-bom.html', context=context)
```

Urls.py

```
path('add_bom/', views.add_bom, name="add_bom"),
path('edit_bom_activity/<str:bomNo>/<str:activity>/', views.edit_bom_activity, name="edit_bom_activity"),
```

Since the template are same it is not somehow entering in `edit_bom_activity` function.

Alternatively

1. I tried to pass parameter in `add_bom/` as

`path('add_bom/<str:bomNo>/<str:activity>/', views.add_bom, {'bomNo': None, 'activity': None}, name="add_bom"),`

But still I couldnt get the success.

2. I tried with `if else` statement for above alternate. But it didnt enter the else condition.

Is there a way on how to allow single template with multiple functions.

Comment: is there any error? or just not showing template?

Comment: No there is no error, its not entering the ```edit``` function. I inserted a print statement in both the functions to debug. It enter when there are no parameters but didnt print anything when have parameters.

Comment: try with just one step url like `edit_bom_activity/<str:bomNo>-<str:activity>/` and separate **bomNo** and **activity** by " - ". if worked, you can handle it yourself

Comment: I tried, still didnt worked out